# Javascript equivalent to Ruby's `send`

Tags: javascript

Trying to loop on all updated field I've got and update them dynamically before saving.

```
Product.findOne({ _id: productNewData['_id'] }, function (err, doc) {
  for (var key in productNewData) {
    # what do I do here?
  }
  doc.save();
});
```

I know that ruby has a send method like this:

```
doc.send(key) = productNewData[key]
```

I guess I can validate the params given and use `eval`. Is there any other way?

Comment: I am not sure of what you're asking. perhaps `doc[key] = productNewData[key]`. what is productNewData ?

Comment: yep, sorry. how do I close?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are two way to acces properties in Javascript:
Using dot notation or brackets. Example:

```
var foo = {bar: 42}
foo.bar // 42
foo["bar"] // 42
var v = "bar"
foo[v] // 42
foo.v // undefined
```

So:

```
Product.findOne({ _id: productNewData['_id'] }, function (err, doc) {
  for (var key in productNewData) {
     doc[key] = productNewData[key]
  }
  doc.save();
});
```